# Time difference from the same method

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I already made some question recently on time issues I was experiencing and I got some good help from a SO member. But still I have some problem that I am unable to solve.
I have this snippet in the home page of my website:

```
private string Datetime()
{
    DateTime nowutc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var cet = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
    var nowcet = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(nowutc, cet);
    return nowcet.ToString("F");
}
```

and it works fine. I get the correct time shown on the label.

I have basically the same code in this method in the login page but it is not returning the correct time in the database (nowcet).

```
 public static void UserLogin(string iPaddress, string uname)
{  
    DateTime nowutc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    var cet = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central European Standard Time");
    var nowcet = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(nowutc, cet);
    const int MaxLength = 46;
    if (uname.Length > MaxLength)
        uname = uname.Substring(0, MaxLength);

    string getconnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(getconnstring);
    conn.Open();
    string ssql = "insert into Logins (IP, uname, dateTime) values ('" +
                  iPaddress + "','" +
                  uname + "','" +
               nowcet.ToString() + "')";//HERE IS WHERE I WRITE THE TIME TO THE DB
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ssql, conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

The difference I get is exactly 3 hours. If the label shows 4:30 pm, the db store 7:30 pm. This problem occurs only on the production server (shared hosting), locally on my machine does not happen.
I do not understand why something like this is happening.  Any hint?

Comment: Is the value of the Datetime as expected before getting written in the Database?

Comment: @CheGueVerra As I said in the question, it is not happening in my local machine but only on the production server.  I try now with a label and let you know.

Comment: Is the timezone on production server the same as that of your local machine? Also I would suggest to parametize our sql parameters.

Comment: @Eric.K.Yung, no the time zone is different. I am CET and the production server is GMT. Could you give me an example about how you would do it?

Comment: See example below. I suspect that when you do nowcet.ToString(), you lose certain information pertain to region-specific.

Answer (score 1):

By no mean this is the answer to your problem. This is just an example of how to pass parameters into your sql.

```
string getconnstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxx"].ConnectionString;
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(getconnstring))
{
    conn.Open();
    string ssql = "insert into Logins (IP, uname, dateTime) values (@iPaddress, @uname, @dateTime)";

    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(ssql, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@iPaddress", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = iPaddress; // make sure the type and size match with what in the db schema
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = uname;  // make sure the type and size match with what in the db schema
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@dateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = nowcet;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```